# Where can I download or how can I activate the dark theme of uikit css (getuikit)?

Tags: css, getuikit

Uikit seems to have a dark theme available.

It can be seen on this demo page: https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/tests/index.html (you can toogle between light and dark theme)

However I don't see how to enable that dark theme in my own page.
Is there a dark theme version of uikit that can be downloaded somewhere?
It seems the download link on the getuikit site only leads to a light theme.

Or is there a class that should be enabled on the `<body>` or the `<html>` tag ?

I don't see how to use that dark theme, or any other theme (if there are other themes I'd be interested in knowing where to download them or how to activate them as well).

Comment: Inspect the body element on that demo page, and you will see that it gets the class `uk-light` or `uk-dark` set dynamically. (Although their use appears to be backwards?)

Comment: Yes, but actually using ``uk-light`` or ``uk-dark`` doesn't turn the theme into a light or a dark theme.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand that there is no dark theme, they switch the background color manually. Not sure now if you have to use ``uk-dark`` on every single element when you do that.

Comment: The classes to put on the individual elements appear to be accessibility helpers only, https://getuikit.com/docs/inverse - so any _actual_ dark mode styling you want, you still have to implement yourself, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge UIKit doesn't support switching between dark/light modes automatically, you will have to implement logic to switch between `uk-light` and `uk-dark` classes for each individual element yourself.

The example site you linked also does dark/light mode switching through [external JavaScript](https://getuikit.com/assets/uikit/tests/js/test.js). Perhaps their implementation could give you some inspiration.